# How can I create a column of data.table that is the output of a function with input multiple columns of the data.table

Tags: r, data.table

ball0, ball1, etc are columns of the `data.table`.
When I try to create the new column,  it takes ball0, ball1, ... to be the whole column.
I would like it to do
`data$list_balls[[1]] <- consec_balls(ball0[[1]] , ball1[[1]], ball2[[1]], ...)`
for each row basically.

```
consec_balls <- function(ball0, ball1 , ball2 , ball3 , ball4) {
  print(ball0)
  consec <- 0
  for (b1 in c(ball0, ball1, ball2, ball3, ball4)) {
    for (b2 in c(ball0, ball1, ball2, ball3, ball4)) {
      if (b1 == b2) {
        next
      }
      if (abs(b1 - b2) <= 2) {
        #2 is kinda arbirary cutoff
        consec <- consec + 1
      }
    }
  }
  return(consec)
}
data <- data[, list_balls := consec_balls(ball0 , ball1, ball2, ball3, ball4 )]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`consec_balls` should be a vectorized function (taking columns vectors as input and returning a vector).

You could either redesign `consec_balls` in a vectorized way, or simply use `Vectorize` :

```
consec_balls_v <- Vectorize(consec_balls)
m <- as.data.table(mtcars)
m[,list_balls:=consec_balls_v(mpg,hp,cyl,wt,disp)]

m
     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb list_balls
 1: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4          0
 2: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4          0
 3: 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1          2
 4: 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1          0
 5: 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2          0
 6: 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1          0
...
```